# Increase Firebase timestamp date on rules

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Hi is there anyway to actually increase the timestamp from this rule? Im using cloud firestore

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    // This rule allows anyone on the internet to view, edit, and delete
    // all data in your Firestore database. It is useful for getting
    // started, but it is configured to expire after 30 days because it
    // leaves your app open to attackers. At that time, all client
    // requests to your Firestore database will be denied.
    //
    // Make sure to write security rules for your app before that time, or else
    // your app will lose access to your Firestore database
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.time < timestamp.date(2020, 1, 16);
    }
  }
}
```

It says there January 16, 2020 and if its less than that it will allow read and write data from my database. But its already January 17 here in the Philippines.

I tried changing the timestamp.date from `2020, 1, 16` to `2020, 3, 15` but still my Flutter app is not reading anything from the database.

What I'm expecting is after I increased the timestamp date, it will allow my app to read from the database until the given time. Right now even if I increased it, the app do not read anything from the database

here's my code:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    return SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Color(0xFF0d192a),
        appBar: CustomAppBar(height: 90),
        drawer: DrawerNiVlad(),
        body: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[


          ArlTitleText('EXPLORE V!'),
          sb5,
          HeaderCarousel(),
          sb30,


          ArlTitleText('DISCOUNT SECTION'),
          sb5,
          // DiscountWidget(),
          sb30,

          ArlTitleText('DUMMY SECTION'),
          ArlBodyText('Lorem ipsum yes yes show boom tarat tarat yea boy Lorem ipsum yes yes show boom tarat tarat yea boy Lorem ipsum yes yes show boom tarat tarat yea boy'),
          sb30,

        ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

The contents of the sections: Discount and Dummy Sections are from the database, it will not appear since it shows in my vscode this error:

[image]

and an email from firebase saying:

```
You chose to start developing in Test Mode, which leaves your Cloud Firestore database completely open to the Internet. Because your app is vulnerable to attackers, your Firestore security rules were configured to stop allowing requests after the first 30 days.
In 0 day(s), all client requests to your Firestore database will be denied. Before that time, please write strong security rules that allow your app to function while appropriately protecting your data. Analysis is run daily; if you've modified your rules in the last 24 hours those changes may not be accounted for.
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show the dart code that performs the query and doesn't work the way you expect.  Be sure to check for errors and show us what the error message is.  Also show us the data you're trying to query and what you expect the query to return from that data.

Comment: updated it thanks! Ive also included the error and the email sent by firebase

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup authentication to fix this issue. If you'd still like to have timestamp-based access, authentication is still needed to be used. I suggest reading through this [guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/insecure-rules) for more details regarding the warnings.